# Using Firebase Admin SDK for Go from AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, go, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

while writing a AppEngine/Go backend that would want to verify firebase id tokens (jwt) I ran across this problem running it on AppEngine:

```
http.DefaultTransport and http.DefaultClient are not available in App Engine. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/
```

The Admin SDK is described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

The following might fix it, only if client.ks was an exported property and thus writable from the app using the lib:

```
client, err := app.Auth()
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf(ctx, "Error getting auth client: %v", err)
    writeJsonResponse(ctx, w, apiResponse{Message: "Firebase error"},
        http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}

// Override the HTTP client by using the urlfetch client to
// make it work under AppEngine
client.ks.HTTPClient = urlfetch.Client(ctx)
```

Are my options limited to a) forking this and manually adding support for urlfetch b) looking for another solutions besides the seemingly OFFICIAL one.. :o

EDIT: As suggested by Gavin, I tried changing this to the following:

```
// Override the default HTTP client with AppEngine's urlfetch
opt := option.WithHTTPClient(urlfetch.Client(ctx))

app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, nil, opt)
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf(ctx, "Error initializing firebase app: %v", err)
    writeJsonResponse(ctx, w, apiResponse{Message: "Firebase error"},
        http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
```

This, however, doesn't do the trick. As far as I can see (having done some source diving in the said library `"firebase.google.com/go"`), the http.Client passed in through the options.Client is only used for Creds creation:

```
creds, err := transport.Creds(ctx, o...)
```

And the actual HTTP communication done in method `refreshKeys()` of `crypto.go` does not use this; instead, it attempts to use the HTTPClient property set in the `httpKeySource`. IMO this is never set anywhere, and therefore it always defaults to the `http.DefaultClient`.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new application with the Firebase Admin SDK, you can pass in options from the "google.golang.org/api/option" package. The option you want to pass in is [WithHTTPClient](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/option#WithHTTPClient).

```
func handleRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    opt := option.WithHTTPClient(urlfetch.Client(ctx))
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, config, opt)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a good idea. However, the library does not appear to use this http.Client for the HTTP communication with the key server; please see my edit. Bug/oversight in the library?

Comment: Good catch. The Admin SDK currently uses `http.DefaultClient` when fetching public key certs. This needs to be fixed to use the client options passed when initializing an App.

Comment: There's a fix under development at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/pull/12. You should be able to try it out by building against the hkj-http-client branch. Any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? It has worked with success for me being hosted in appengine.

Comment: @Gavin Yes I did try it. @HiranyaJayathilaka any estimate when this would be in the version that you get with `go get` ?

Comment: This was released today: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/go#1.0.1